# Aligning <main> with background-image

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm creating a site with the idea of the site ticket master, however I ran into a problem with the background image and the  part of my page. The  section of the page isn't lining up with the background-image. I have set to `background-size: cover;` For some reason when I shrink the view-port screen it gives white space on the smallest viewing screen. Can anyone help?

I tried using media queries but it still isn't working. I just want the  to line up with the background image I have set up.

https://replit.com/@SRJCEthanWilde/CS50A-Module13-52-JosohamyMendez#index.html

That is my workspace for this project. Feel free to edit but not directly to the site and post response here.

Comment: Your demo site is a 404.

Comment: @davidleininger try this one https://cs50a-module13-52-josohamymendez.srjcethanwilde.repl.co/

Comment: I think that when the image achieve its full width, it cannot expand more into the container. I'm not sure of that but that's the most logic thing

Comment: @Eli-ott the background-image isnt the problem. The <main> element is whats not aligning properly with the background image. any suggestions?

Comment: oh... my bad didn't read well enough. But I think that @davidleininger answer could be the right one

Comment: yes it was what i needed but thanks for your help too maybe it was my phrasing of the question? you did good tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your example that are causing this to work incorrectly.

First you have `height: 1000px;` on your `body`. So, `background-size: cover;` is working, but your height is causing the problem. Remove that and it will start filling the whole screen.

Second, you define a background color using `background` and that voids out the `background-position` that is higher in the cascade. Use `background-color` instead.

That should solve it.

Comment: that was perfect! thank you wise one! u should change your name to master yoda because that was a yoda worthy answer!